# How to fade an image sequence into another in cmd with magick?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

I'm new to the magick library and also this cmd syntax hurts me so much. I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have 2 folders, each of them contains 100 png files. I want to render a smooth transition between these images like this:

The first image in the first folder should be overlapped with the first image in the second folder with 1% opacity.

The 45th image in the first folder should be overlapped with the 45th image in the second folder with 45% opacity, and so on...

My files are named like frame000.png, frame045.png (padded with zeros), which is further complicates the problem.

I try to achieve this combining a for loop in a batch script and a magick command, but it seems like nothing is happening, when I run it it just prints this text to the cmd window 100 times:

```
SET NUM=x SET PADDED=00NUM SET PADDED=PADDED:~-3 magick composite -dissolve PADDEDPADDEDPADDEDPADDED.png
```

I think the problem is in my batch syntax, but I can't figure it out. Heres what I have in render.bat:

```
FOR /L %%x IN (0,1,99) DO ^
SET NUM=%x ^
SET PADDED=00%NUM% ^
SET PADDED=%PADDED:~-3% ^
magick composite -dissolve %x -gravity Center "frl1/frame%PADDED%.png" "frl2/frame%PADDED%.png" -alpha SET "output/%PADDED%.png"
pause
```

I tried changing the variable references to `%x`, `%%x`, `%x%`, but none of them gave me the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `^` means "Line continuation" - this is not how batchfiles work.

And you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%x IN (0,1,99) DO (
  SET PADDED=00%%x
  SET PADDED=!PADDED:~-3!
  magick composite -dissolve %%x -gravity Center "frl1/frame!   PADDED!.png" "frl2/frame!PADDED!.png" -alpha SET "output/!PADDED!.png"
)
pause
```

(Note: I removed an unnecessary variable)

Comment: It seems like the variable doesn't work in the strings, now magick throw this error on each iteration: `unable to open image 'frl1/!PADDED!.png' [...]`

Comment: Try again. Added a line.

Comment: I just noticed the link and read that, and it works. Thanks for your answer!